# External display on Vortex III laptop with Ivy Bridge and NVIDIA GTX 675M

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus

I am planning to buy a Vortex III laptop:
http://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/notebooks/VortexIII-15/
but I am not sure if I will be able to connect and use it with the external display. Does anyone have any experience with this or similar machine?

It is an optimus laptop with Intel HD 4000 and GeForce GTX 675M. I do not intend to be using GTX 675M with Linux. It will be used exclusivelly for gaming (under the other OS).

I know that in optimus-enabled laptops the HDMI port is normally wired to the NVIDIA card so that rules HDMI port out. But the machine has DVI and Display Port as well. Can I use one of these to plug a second monitor and still have a laptop display on?
I know there are similar threads on a topic but none of them seems to cover the machine I am looking to buy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself... I eventually bought this laptop and can confirm that DVI output works out of the box without using the dedicated GeForce GPU. According to the pcspecialist support, HDMI will work as well but I was not able to test it since I do not have any HDMI capable monitor.

EDIT: So I did test HDMI in the end, and it works okay without the dedicated GPU.